# Symfony2 Doctrine Form - How to get the project object in another class?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

Users can comment on different projects (OneToMany relation Project -> Comment). If a comment is created I need to know which user did it and for which project. I already figured out how to get the current user, but I don't know how to get the project object.

Here is the createAction controller, my question now, how can I access the current project which is beeing displayed.

```
 /**
 * Creates a new Comment entity.
 *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Comment();


        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entity->setUser($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('dbe_comment_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('DbeDonaciBundle:Comment:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Changes I made:

```
dbe_comment_create:
pattern:  /project/{id}/comment
defaults: { _controller: "DbeDDDDBundle:Comment:create" }
requirements: { _method: post }
```

Twig:

```
{{ render(controller('DbeDDDDBundle:Comment:new', { 'id': entity.id})) }}
```

Here is the error message I get, because I'm rendering the new method and not the create.

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "dbe_comment_create".") in DbeDDDDDBundle:Project:show.html.twig at line 305.
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have a shortcut for current user: `$this->getUser()`

As for project. You mast pass it somehow. Two ways come to my mind.

1. Add a hidden field containing project id to your form.
2. Have your project id in route (and therefor as action parameter too).

Generally I would opt for #2 since it follows Restful conventions. Make your `create_comment` path: `projects/{projectId}/comments` POST.

That way you will have $projectId parameter available in your action.

Comment: Hey Igor, thanks already for sending me into the correct direction. I still have some problems because I'm rendering the new method. how can i do that and how can I afterward get the object id into my controller?